# How can I use BUCK build with a pod that has several files with the same name?

Tags: c++, ios, realm, cocoapods, buck

I'm trying to use BUCK with the [Realm pod](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa).

I've set up my buck file as:

```
apple_pod_lib(
    name = "Realm",
    visibility = ["PUBLIC"],
    exported_headers = glob([
        "Realm/**/*.h",
        "Realm/**/*.hpp",
    ]),
    srcs = glob([
        "Realm/**/.{m,mm,cpp}",
    ]),
)

apple_pod_lib(
    name = "RealmSwift",
    visibility = ["PUBLIC"],
    swift_version = "4",
    deps = [
        "//Pods:Realm"
    ],
    srcs = glob([
        "RealmSwift/**/*.swift",
    ]),
)
```

using the pod macro from [Airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/BuckSample/blob/master/Config/buck_rule_macros.bzl#L4).

However I can't build my project as this failed with

```
In target '//Pods:Realm', 'Realm/history.hpp' maps to the following header files:
- /BuckSample/Pods/Realm/include/core/realm/sync/history.hpp
- /BuckSample/Pods/Realm/include/core/realm/history.hpp

Please rename one of them or export one of them to a different path.
```

I've also tried manually specifying the files & headers to include, looking at the PodSpec from those repos, but I could not get it to work as I was then missing some files for the project to compile in Xcode.

Comment: It looks like what I need it to have BUCK keep the path to the header in instead of trying to export everything to "history.hpp" so that this makes sense https://github.com/realm/realm-object-store/blob/f59cb85414b22722660ad06186357ecfa01bc64f/src/shared_realm.cpp#L34-L42

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I was able to install the prebuilt framework through Carthage as:

```
# Cartfile
github "realm/realm-cocoa"

# Carthage/BUCK
prebuilt_apple_framework(
    name = "Realm",
    framework = "Build/iOS/Realm.framework",
    preferred_linkage = "shared",
    visibility = ["PUBLIC"],
)

prebuilt_apple_framework(
    name = "RealmSwift",
    framework = "Build/iOS/RealmSwift.framework",
    preferred_linkage = "shared",
    visibility = ["PUBLIC"],
    deps = [
      ":Realm",
    ]
)

# Where my library is
apple_library(
    name = "LibraryWithRealm",
    visibility = ["PUBLIC"],
    swift_version = "5.0",
    modular = True,
    deps = [
        "//Carthage:RealmSwift",
    ]
)
```